# При нажатии на кнопку скрыть grid и изменить контент кнопки при помощи тригеров

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет.

Есть кнопка с текстом "collapse" и ниже Grid.

По определенной причине использовать C# код нельзя. Необходимо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, текст кнопки изменялся на "Details" и Grid становился невидимым, а при повторном нажатии грид появлялся и название кнопки обратно изменялось на "Collapse".

Нашел, что можно реализовать через EventTrigger

Я сделал чтобы Grid становился невидимым (Visibility = hidden) и изменялся текст на кнопке.

Как сделать чтобы при повторном нажатии он становился (Visibility = visible)?
И текст менялся обратно на "Collapse"

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger SourceName="button1" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="button1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Details">

                        </DiscreteStringKeyFrame>
                    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <Button Content="Collapse" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,40,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
        </Button>
        <Grid x:Name="CollapsedGrid" Margin="40,97,69,37" Visibility="Visible">
            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan='2' BorderThickness='1' BorderBrush='#FFD4D4D4' Padding='10,5'>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width='Auto'/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width='6'/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width='*'/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
                        <RowDefinition Height='5'/>
                        <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
                        <RowDefinition Height='5'/>
                        <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
                        <RowDefinition Height='*'/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text='gfgfgfgfgfgfgf:'/>
                    <StackPanel  Orientation='Horizontal' Grid.Column='2'>
                        <TextBlock Text='100000000000000000.00' Margin='0,0,6,0'/>
                        <TextBlock Text='eur'/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text='tttttttttttttt:'  Grid.Row='2'/>
                    <StackPanel  Orientation='Horizontal'  Grid.Row='2' Grid.Column='2'  >
                        <TextBlock Text='0'   Margin='0,0,6,0'/>
                        <TextBlock Text='eur'/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text='rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr:'  Grid.Row='4'/>
                    <StackPanel  Orientation='Horizontal'  Grid.Row='4' Grid.Column='2' >
                        <TextBlock Text='10000000'   Margin='0,0,6,0'/>
                        <TextBlock Text='eur'/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так(Button-->ToogleButton)

```html
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <ToggleButton Name="YourButton" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Margin="54,40,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
      <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
          <Setter Property="Content" Value="Collapse"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Content" Value="Expand"/>
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
    <Grid Name="CollapsedGrid" Margin="40,97,69,37">
      <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=YourButton, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Grid.Style>
      <Border Grid.ColumnSpan='2' BorderThickness='1' BorderBrush='#FFD4D4D4' Padding='10,5'>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width='Auto'/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width='6'/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width='*'/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
            <RowDefinition Height='5'/>
            <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
            <RowDefinition Height='5'/>
            <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
            <RowDefinition Height='*'/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Text='gfgfgfgfgfgfgf:'/>
          <StackPanel  Orientation='Horizontal' Grid.Column='2'>
            <TextBlock Text='100000000000000000.00' Margin='0,0,6,0'/>
            <TextBlock Text='eur'/>
          </StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text='tttttttttttttt:'  Grid.Row='2'/>
          <StackPanel  Orientation='Horizontal'  Grid.Row='2' Grid.Column='2'  >
            <TextBlock Text='0'   Margin='0,0,6,0'/>
            <TextBlock Text='eur'/>
          </StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text='rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr:'  Grid.Row='4'/>
          <StackPanel  Orientation='Horizontal'  Grid.Row='4' Grid.Column='2' >
            <TextBlock Text='10000000'   Margin='0,0,6,0'/>
            <TextBlock Text='eur'/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
      </Border>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Grid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (f == 0)
            {
                Grid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                f = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Grid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                f = 0;

            }
        }
```